# Why not file.wav all can be played on Java?

Tags: java, audio

I believe that on Java, using the following code, could play all files `.wav` but I was wrong, I though that I was doing some bad-code, but trying with 3 different .wav files, I realize that throws UnsupportedAudioFileException with 2 of them:

```
private void playAudio() {

    try {

         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(
                 MainM.class.getResource("dinero2.wav"));
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();

      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

**QUESTION:** Why not .wav all can be played on Java?

Comment: Perhaps not all of them have the same encoding. Check the encodings of your wav files (the way to do this depends on your operating system).

Comment: You could try using javaFX to play your .wav files using FX's built in AudioClip class.

Comment: Sorry but we cannot use javaFX because we're studying just Swing, jeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Finally, got the explicit answer right here: [Reading and writing wav files in java](http://computermusicblog.com/blog/2008/08/29/reading-and-writing-wav-files-in-java/)